# Sequelize where query of a one to many association attribute?

Tags: mysql, database, sequelize.js

I have the following tables in a database:

`Users: id|name|age
 Hobbies: id|user_id|hobby`

In sequelize I have the following associations:

`Users.hasMany(Hobbies)
 Hobbies.belongTo(Users)`

To retrieve a list of users along with their hobbies the query is as follows:

`Users.findAll(include: [{model: Hobbies}])`

I map the result of the query to a domain object.

The result of the query looks something like this:

`[{id: 1, name: 'John', age: 20, hobbies: ['fishing', 'running']}]`

I am trying to return a list of users that have a hobby of fishing.

As I understand it I can apply a where query on the association itself like this:

`Users.findAll(include: [{model: Hobbies, where: {hobby: 'fishing'}}])`

but this will still return all users, and will only return the hobbies for each user that are fishing.

Is there a way to apply a where query at the user level based on their hobbies?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change the join type. Sequelize by default uses left outer join while joining two models but if you change that to inner join by setting `required` to `true` you will get intended results -

```
Users.findAll(include: [{model: Hobbies, where: {hobby: 'fishing'}, required : true}])
```

I hope it helps!